# parse quoted string into tokens in javascript

Tags: parsing

I need to parse expression like
'a' 'b' 'cd ef'
three tokens
how can this be done in javascript?par

Comment: Can you expand upon your question a bit?  What are you trying to parse, and what would you like to end up with?  Four spaces at the beginning of a line makes a code indent.

Comment: Maybe he is trying to split the string into tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var re = /'([^']*)'/g;
var input = "'foo' 'bar' 'omg wtf'";
var hit;
while (hit = re.exec(input)) {
    print(hit[1]);
}
```

Comment: Note however, that this simple snippet does not account for escaped quotes inside the tokens.